# Should Bower managed dependencies be checked in to repository

Tags: javascript, bower

I've come my way from java development to development of complex Javascript projects. In Java build systems you don't checkin your dependencies (your jars) to sourcvode repository but let a build tool (maven, gradle, ...) manage that dependencies for you.

Now bower seems for me to be something like Maven to handle that dependency things for me. What I wonder about: Should I checkin the libs downloaded by bower or should I just checkin a script describing the dependencies I have and keep my repository free of thrid party code? Whats best practise? (And why?)

Comment: Don't include bower or npm modules in the repo. That defeats a significant portion of their purpose. NPM modules anyway can also contain platform-specific code.

Comment: Have a look at the pros and cons listed by Addy Osmani in his blog post http://addyosmani.com/blog/checking-in-front-end-dependencies/

Comment: My recommendation is to avoid checking it into your source repo. If you need it for deployment, then create your deployment builds as and when necessary or look into CI servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some pros and cons when you check the dependencies in your source control. The main reason for checking your dependencies would be to avoid issues while deploying your app. For example if Github is having network issues you can't deploy to production because your dependencies can't be fetched.

On the other hand the benefit of only having your bower.json file in your project instead of the whole bower_components folder is that it will keep your repository smaller. If you use CI, you can run `bower install`, run tests to see if everything works, and then deploy the exact copy in your production server.

Ultimately it is up to you to decide the best approach.